# What is "unable to open object pack directory: .git/objects/pack: Not a directory" error?

Tags: macos, command-line, git, open-source

When I use `git add .` or `git commit -m 'My message'` I give following error:

`error: unable to open object pack directory: .git/objects/pack: Not a directory`

Also when I use `git commit -m 'My message'` I can make commit but I get mentioned error.

How can I resolve this problem? And what are causes of this error?

My git version: 2.19.1